my fluentsearch input box is not letting me type anything
as the title states I am trying to implement a fluentsearch input box that has an oninput event that fires off the SearchEmployees method everytime the user types into the input. for reasons unknown, the input box does not allow me to type anything. Basically when I enter a keystroke, it clears the input box, not allowing me to type anything into it. I did notice that if I use the bind-value:after directive and assign SearchEmployees to that, it works, the problem as that I dont want the user to have to hit enter to fire off the method, I want it to be on every keystroke
@page "/Sandbox"
@inject IDbContextFactory<SFSChecklistContext> _contextFactory
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web

<AuthorizeView Policy="SuperAdmin">
    <Authorized>
        <!-- Input field with searchEmployees method -->

    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <FluentSearch @ref=searchTest
                      @bind-Value="@inputValue"
                      Placeholder="Search for Employee"
                     @oninput="SearchEmployees"
                      />
        <br />
        <ul>
            @foreach (var employee in FilteredEmployees)
            {
                <li>@employee.FirstName @employee.LastName</li>
            }
        </ul>
        <p>
            You searched for: @inputValue
        </p>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code {
    private string? inputValue;
    private bool isSearching;
    private FluentSearch? searchTest;

    private List<Employee> FilteredEmployees { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private async Task SearchEmployees()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputValue))
        {
            using (var _context = await _contextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync())
            {
                EmployeeRepo repo = new EmployeeRepo(_context);
                FilteredEmployees = await repo.SearchEmployeesAsync(inputValue);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            FilteredEmployees.Clear();
        }

        // Update the UI after the search operation
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}


I have tried implementing both the oninput and bind-value:after directives , I want the user to be able to see the results of the UL change as they type into the input field

Your problem is you aren't binding correctly.
You bind is only updating inputValue on the onChange event, so when @oninput="SearchEmployees" executes, inputValue is empty and your logic clears the list.  It also triggers a UI update. inputValue is empty which is what gets passed back to the control in the bind parameters, overwriting the value you entered.
Here's a refactored version of your code that I believe behaves in the way you expect.
Note:

Immediate is the FluentUI method of setting the control to update on each keystroke.
after is called after inputValue has been updated by the bind and does the search.
No need to call StateHasChanged, the UI handler for the bind update has it built in.

@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new Fluent Blazor app.
<FluentSearch @ref=searchTest
              @bind-Value="@inputValue"
              Immediate
              @bind-Value:after="SearchEmployees"
              Placeholder="Search for Employee" />
<br />
<ul>
    @foreach (var employee in FilteredEmployees)
    {
        <li>@employee.FirstName @employee.LastName</li>
    }
</ul>
<p>
    You searched for: @inputValue
</p>

@code {
    private string? inputValue;
    private bool isSearching;
    private FluentSearch? searchTest;

    private List<Employee> FilteredEmployees { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();

    private async Task SearchEmployees()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(inputValue))
        {
            // Fake an async data call
            await Task.Delay(10);
            this.FilteredEmployees = this.Employees
                .Where(item => item.FullName.Contains(inputValue, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                .ToList();
        }
        else
            FilteredEmployees.Clear();

        // not required
        //StateHasChanged();
    }

    public record Employee(string FirstName, string LastName)
    {
        public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
    }

    private List<Employee> Employees = new()
    {
        new("Fred", "Bloggs"),
        new("Fred", "Smith"),
        new("John", "Smith"),
    };
}

